# Starting AWS Batch from SQS queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-batch

I have a long running batch job that am planning to move to AWS Batch. Since it takes couple of hours to run this job, I cant use AWS Lambda.

But, one of the requirement is to trigger this job from my AWS SQS queue.

I couldn't find any reference documentation on this. Is it even feasible?

Comment: Do you need to just trigger the batch job or do you need to monitor and notify once the job is complete?

Comment: I just need to trigger the job when a new item is added to the SQS queue. Monitoring and notification is not a priority now, as we have other systems that can do the same.

Comment: In that case, why not have a Lambda Trigger configured for the SQS Queue that'd just initiate the Batch job using a boto3 Batch client.submit_job() and exit out with a successful or failed job-start status or the actual submit_job return status whichever you need?

Comment: +1 to what @vivekveeramani suggested. If you are familiar with Lambda already you can use it (and the SQS integration) to invoke a batch job rather than running the logic itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement below method on listening of SQS message :

```
public void onMessage( Message message ) throws JMSException {

    SQSTextMessage sqsTextMessage = ( SQSTextMessage ) message;
    String text = sqsTextMessage.getText();
  
    AWSBatch awsBatch = AWSBatchClientBuilder.standard()
       .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
       .withRegion("region")
       .build();

    SubmitJobRequest submitRequest = new SubmitJobRequest()
       .withJobDefinition("job-definition-name")
       .withJobName("job-name")
       .withJobQueue("job-queue");
  
    SubmitJobResult submitResult = awsBatch.submitJob(submitRequest);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, while [SQS can natively trigger AWS Lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html), it does not support this same native triggering with Batch jobs. As a workaround, you'll have to just trigger a Lambda that implements a call to the [Batch SubmitJob API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/APIReference/API_SubmitJob.html) using REST or your favorite AWS SDK (e.g. [Python Client.submit_job](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/batch/client/submit_job.html)).

NOTE: Depending on your architecture, you could leverage EventBridge, which allows you to configure [API destinations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-destinations.html), which are HTTP endpoints that you can invoke as the target of an EventBridge rule. In this case, [EventBridge Rule could directly trigger Batch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch-cwe-target.html), allowing you to potentially remove SNS/SQS/Lambda from your architecture.